# Forwarding apache requests (port 80) to Tomcat (port 8080)?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6

I want to run a Tomcat application through a regular website URL, such as `www.xyz.com`. I would like the root of this domain to act as the base directory for the web application, so each request to `www.xyz.com/a/b/c` becomes `www.abc.com:8080/myApp/a/b/c`. Ideally, I would be able to do this transparently and only for certain webapps.

`www.abc.com:8080` should still respond to requests.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 15):

```
ProxyPass        / http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/
```

Read more about [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: this is the best solution to do this

Comment: To address the "only for certain webapps" side, just make the redirect path deeper. So:
ProxyPass        /a/b/c http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/a/b/c
ProxyPassReverse /a/b/c http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/a/b/c

To proxy all except certain paths, leave the ProxyPassReverse line but replace the ProxyPass lines with RewriteRules (making sure to use the [P] option to proxy rather than redirect), and make earlier rules to not proxy those paths.

RewriteRule /notproxied - [L]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.abc.com:8080/myApps/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/

Comment: where do I add those lines?

Comment: @MinaMichael The [mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) states:Context: server config, virtual host, directory

Answer (score 3):

You can use mod_rewrite in Apache to do this. Load mod_rewrite in your Apache and in your  www.xyz.com vhost add the following rule:

`RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/$1`

This should do the magic.

More info about mod_rewrite [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

**EDIT**: In order to keep the site name in the browsers, use mod_proxy as well by just appending a [P] at the end of the RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/$1 [P]`

This will force Apache to act as a proxy for that URL instead of just rewriting the URL.

Comment: This causes the browser to actually redirect. This works, but I would prefer if the site appeared as `www.xyz.com` from the user's side.

Comment: use mod_proxy as well, and in the end of the RewriteRule append a [P], like this:

RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.abc.com:8080/myApp/$1 [P].

I've also edited the answer above to include this info.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler method for doing this is to just add a Virtual Host entry in your Apache conf file.  Usually located in /etc/httpd/conf, add something like this at the end of the Virtual Host section:

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
ServerName tomcatpage.yourdomain.com
ServerAlias tomcatpage.yourdomain.com
Redirect permanent / http://tomcatpage.yourdomain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart your Apache service and you are done.